# WordPress: wpLink `this.textarea is undefined`

Tags: wordpress

In a plugin, we're using a button & text input to trigger the wpLink modal. All works well, until we hit a template that removes the main content editor and relies only on metaboxes for the page content.

The error we're getting is `this.textarea is undefined`. The code we're using is:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.pluginxyz-add-link', function( event ) {
    wpActiveEditor = true;
    wpLink.open();
    return false;
});
```

So I assume there is some dependency to the main editor. I can't find explicit info/documentation around this.. anyone have a suggestion about making this work *without* the main editor?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just figured this out. In our code, the ONLY sibling text input is always where the value will go.

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.pluginxyz-add-link', function( event ) {
    clickedEle = $( this );
    textBoxID = $( clickedEle ).siblings( 'input[type=text]' ).attr( 'id' );

    wpActiveEditor = true;
    wpLink.open( textBoxID);
    return false;
});
```